# Webrtc screen capture resolution android

Tags: android, webrtc, screen-capture

How can i change screen capture resolution to 1280x720 in webrtc android, using `ScreenCapturerAndroid`.

i tried to set

```
capturer.startCapture(1280, 720, 0);
```

but it doest't wotk

it just reduces the picture and shows it small